# Legacy ASP site issue

Tags: iis, asp-classic, vbscript, iis-6

I'm dealing with an issue where there was a site setup, and the default.htm used an iframe which pointed to an ASP directory. It seems like the ASP directory isn't readable and not processed - is there anything special that needs to be done to the ASP directory like permissions-wise?

```
wwwroot/sitename
<iframe src="ASP/file.asp"></iframe>
```

`wwwroot/sitename/ASP/file.asp` exists, and several other asp files but they aren't getting referenced by the iframe.

**Update:** I'm getting a 404..

> The page cannot be found

I think I have to create a virtual directory and name it ASP. I never use IIS though - does anyone know how this works? And would I need to restart IIS after creating the virtual directory?

**Update #2: More info..**

```
Execute permissions: Scripts Only 
Application name: asp
For Authentication Methods, "Integrated Windows authentication" is checked
Local Path: Read
```

**Update #3:** I can access asp/file.htm file fine. Can anyone provide code for a simple test I could do to see if its working properly ( I have no ASP/VBScript experience )..

one of the top of the pages contains `<%@ LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT"%>`

Comment: Are you getting an error message?

Comment: Is the frame blank or are you seeing an error?  If you right-click and choose Properties in the frame, what address does it show?  If you visit that address directly, do you see the ASP file?

Comment: I'm getting a 404. Pretty sure it's readable, I added a virtual directory but didnt restart IIS or anything special since I'm not sure how to.. ( remember again I have NEVER DEALT WITH IIS BEFORE )

Answer (score 2):

Is this IIS6 by any chance? In IIS, under Web Sites there is a folder called Web Service Extensions.  Make sure Active Server Pages are set to Allow and not Prohibited!

Comment: My bad thought I typed 6.. yeah.. I'll check on Monday

Answer (score 1):

When you create a virtual directory for an ASP site in IIS, you have to make sure it is allowed to execute scripts.  What version of IIS are you using?  In 5.0 and 6.0, there should be a checkbox Run Scripts (such as ASP).  Make sure that's checked.

Comment: I checked the box that said run ASP, it still 404s.. do I need to restart IIS?

Comment: You shouldn't need to restart IIS when adding a virtual directory.  Doing so might clear up any other issues, though.  At a command prompt, type iisreset.  Also, check permissions on the folder in Windows Explorer.  IUSR_<name of your box> should have read permissions.

Comment: I can access an .htm file, so perhaps it's something with the ASP settings or web config?

Comment: Probably the server configuration, then.  Check Macka's answer; IIS 6 prohibits legacy ASP by default.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting a test.html file in the root directory of the site and then try to open it through wwwroot/sitename/asp/test.html - .html files won't be processed by asp.dll and so should display if the site is setup correctly even if there is some kind of asp.dll problem.

If you can't see a html file then I guess you will need to configure the website in IIS (not sure if a virtual directory is necessary from the information given) - check the 'home' tab to see if the path to the application is correct first.

If you can see the html file then I'd guess that asp is not properly installed (but that is a guess).

Comment: Ah interesting, I can access an .htm file in it but not the asp files.

Comment: It could be caused by an MS security patch, try: http://forums.iis.net/p/1164886/1933813.aspx#1933813 which shows you how to get .asp pages served again on IIS6.  HTH.